# How can I suggest a preferred format for a New-Object?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating new objects in `PowerShell` like this:

```
# create new object
$res = New-Object PSObject

# assign properties
$res | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name Passed -Value $Passed
$res | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name Duration -Value $Duration
$res | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name Name -Value $TestCase.Name
$res | Add-Member Noteproperty -Name Message -Value $Message

# return result
$res
```

When I call this code, the `$res` result item gets displayed in a table format. I can force the format used by adding `| Format-Table` as well.

Is it possible to construct the new object in a way that I can force a specific default format to use when it gets displayed? (ie: can I force `Format-Table` or `Format-List` by adding some property or meta-data on the object?)

Comment: Are you trying to save time on typing? Use `| ft` or `| fl` respectively.

Comment: See `help about_Format.ps1xml`

Comment: @Neolisk no, i'm trying to do the right thing by default :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know to get a standard format for a type is to create and load a format file  (see [about_Format.ps1xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847831.aspx)). Format files "decide" which format to use based on the object's type name.  So, when you create your custom object, make sure to also give it a custom type name, so you can write a custom view for it:

```
$res = New-Object PSObject
$res.PSTypeNames.Insert(0, 'Result')
```

Then, in your format file, use `Result` as the type name.  Probably a good idea to use a better name than `Results`.

Format files have to be loaded before they can be used.  This is easy if the format file is part of a module, a little more work if it's a loose format file your scripts will load individually.

You can also write your own format function which uses `Format-Table` and/or `Format-List` internally, to display the object the way you want, e.g.

```
function Format-TestCaseResult
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject
    )
    process
    {
        $InputObject | Format-Table -AutoSize
    }
}
```